# Objects continuously cloning C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello there i have created a system that finds a specific model and spawns it  however  it will consciously clone the object over and over despite me trying to find ways to end the function or False the bool which does not work, any suggestions on how this can be done would be great. 
Thank you for your time and patience.

```
 void Update()
{




 if (NKCell.GetComponent<ModelChangeScript>().HighqualityModel == true )
    {

        HQModelSpawn();



public void HQModelSpawn()
{
    HighQualityModel = false;

    Transform[] HQTransforms = this.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();



    foreach (Transform t in HQTransforms)
    {
        if (t.gameObject.CompareTag("HighQualityModel"))

        {
            HQMesh = t.gameObject;


            Instantiate(t.gameObject, CurrentPosition, Currentrotation);




            transform.position = CurrentPosition;
            transform.rotation = Currentrotation;



            Debug.Log("Found " + t);

            break;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Update will be run every frames... perhaps you should have instantiate the object in Start instead?

Comment: i have just tried it and it does not work that way , i belive start is for only when the Scene is initiated .

Comment: @ryand444 Start is the start of the objects life, not the scenes life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to do this in [Start Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), if you are not willing to do this then, updated code is given below, you should false the bool also as below code suggested.

```
void Update()
{
 if (NKCell.GetComponent<ModelChangeScript>().HighqualityModel == true )
    {
        HQModelSpawn();
NKCell.GetComponent<ModelChangeScript>().HighqualityModel = false;
     }


public void HQModelSpawn()
{
    HighQualityModel = false;

    Transform[] HQTransforms = this.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();



    foreach (Transform t in HQTransforms)
    {
        if (t.gameObject.CompareTag("HighQualityModel"))

        {
            HQMesh = t.gameObject;


            Instantiate(t.gameObject, CurrentPosition, Currentrotation);




            transform.position = CurrentPosition;
            transform.rotation = Currentrotation;



            Debug.Log("Found " + t);

            break;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This Does work , thanks  , it only seems to work in Update just to let yourself and anyone else know , at least with my code.